# Как ограничить grid только 2 элементами по оси Y и бесконечным количеством со скролом по оси x

Tags: html5, css-grid

У меня есть два контейнера:

(является grid'дом)

```
        <div className='Reviews'>внутри находятся много-много(или нет) контейнеров review(код ниже)</div>
```

и
(вот тот самый контейнер)

```
          <div className='review'>
        <div className='ReviewContent'>
          <div className='NamePositionCompanyAndStars'>
            <div className='NameAndPosition'>
            <p className='Name'>Олександр</p>
            <div className='Position'>
              <p className='PositionSign'>Co-CEO</p>
              <p className='OfSign'>of</p>
              <p className='NameOfCompany'>Feed Motion ADS</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className='Stars'>
              <img src={images.starrate} alt="" />
              <img src={images.starrate} alt="" />
              <img src={images.starrate} alt="" />
              <img src={images.starrate} alt="" />
              <img src={images.starrate} alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <p className='UserReview'>Були проведені чудові роботи. Налаштували оптимізували та підказали</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

я не знаю сколько будет елементов в сетке, может быть их будет 10, потом 30, потом 50, только лишь нужно всегда иметь 2 елемента по Y и бесконечность (свободное количество) по X, забыл, какой код за это отвечает, но желательно, что бы они распределялись сверху вниз

мне нужно поставить grid вот таким образом со скролом вправо [image: Пример сетки из Figma]

вот эти белые квадратики - это и есть мой второй контейнер просто я отправил CSS код без "косметичестих" настроек

CSS код обох контейнеров:

```
.Reviews{
display: grid;
width: 100%;
height: 874px;

gap: 20px; /*это всё что я смог понять в grid*/
z-index: 9;
margin-top: 58px;
margin-left: 90px;
}

.review{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 703px;
    height: 425px;

    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь это вам поможет)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.grid-block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
  <div class="grid-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: >бесконечным количеством со скролом по оси x  :) `grid-auto-flow: column` потерялся

Comment: Надеюсь, вы не против? )

Comment: хахах, я методом тыка и гугла разобрался с этим, просто лучшие ! я не могу описать насколько я счастилив и благодарен, что мне помогли